# in C#: looping through a string or a string array if the index is higher than the length of the string

Tags: c#, substring, indexoutofboundsexception, caesar-cipher, outofrangeexception

So I'm very new to C# and trying to learn some basics so I apologize if I have any of the terminology wrong, please feel free to let me know if I can clarify anything.

I'm trying to fetch an object of the index position, decided by another int variable, in a string array. The variable must be able to be larger than the number of objects in the string array, so far I get "IndexOutOfRangeException, which is to be expected. I would like it to keep looking and just start over in the array, much like a loop would work.

So these are the relevant strings for what I've tried:

```
string alf = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

string[] alflist = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
```

What I've tried is this:
`string output = alflist[Encryption.key];`

Where Encryption.key is called form another class, and this is the int that could be (and in this instance is) larger than the 26 positions of alflist.

If Encryption.key = 30 I would like output to be = "e" (since a=0 & 26).

I have also tried to use `alf.substring(Encryption.key, 1)` but I get the same error.

Thanks for any guidance on this

Comment: Use the modulo operator: `%` to "wrap" the key value.

Comment: First check the Encryption.key value is greater then the length of variable "alf", if yes then subtract the value of the Encryption.key value with length of variable "alf" until the Encryption.key is inferior then length of variable "alf" using recrussive function or use the modulo operator. After that pass the final value as index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulus (`%`) operator. Also, strings can already provide characters by index using the same bracket notation as arrays; there's no need to create a separate array:

```
string alf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int index = Encryption.Key % alf.Length;
char result = alf[index];
```

Or if you need a string instead of a character:

```
string alf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int index = Encryption.Key % alf.Length;
string result = alf[index].ToString();
```

But if you *did* want an array, you can could get it like this:

```
string alf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var alfArray = alf.ToCharArray(); // List is not an array. It means something different in C#
```

Comment: Thank you :) How would it work if the Encryption.Key would be much larger, like 5000. since the "modulus" would return 4974?
And wouldn't it also return a negative value if Encryption.Key is lower than 26?
I would need it to be pretty dynamic, but I guess I could build an if that loops the modulus until it's less than 26. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You seemed to got what modulo does wrong. alf.Length is 26 and the modulo will never be greater. Just like you can add millions of hours to the current time. Still your watch will never show a value greater 24h.

Comment: @WilhelmBlom 5000 % 26 is **8**, not 4974. And modulus will only return a negative value if one of the operands is negative.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I misunderstood Modulus, will do some reading up on it. It did however solve my problem. Thank you so much :)

This is what I used (sorry I don't know how to get it into a code block from a comment) Also thanks for clearing up list/array:

int index;
                if (Encryption.key <= alf.Length)
                {
                    index = Encryption.key;
                }
                else
                {
                    index = Encryption.key % alf.Length;
                }
                
                char output = alf[index];

Comment: @WilhelmBlom You can remove the if check. If `Encryption.Key` is between 0 and 25, then `Encryption.Key % 26` will result in the original `Encryption.Key`, and it's faster to run a modulus than a conditional `if` check.